# Android Facebook howto Post

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

i have the following problem: I tried to post sth. to Facebook by using ACTION_SEND Intent to pass a String to the Facebook application.

Now I know this is currently not possible.

I don't want to code my own Facebook login, logout, session handling stuff in my application.

Question is:
If someone has the Facebook App installed and is logged in,
can I use the authentification information to post sth. on his Facebook wall?

Or, what is the easiest way to get sth. posted?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Spring Social Facebook](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) library.  It will take care of all the OAuth stuff for you and provide you with a nice Facebook API you can interact with.  The API allows you to do a lot more things than just post.

The downside is you have to install the jar files with your app and do a little setup.  There is a good example of how to do this for Android in the spring-android-showcase-client in the [spring-android-samples project](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-android-samples).

Comment: is there no way to use the original installed facebook app ?